# Como prevenir que a connection pool do Hibernate lance a exceção do número limite de conexões?

Tags: hibernate

Eu tenho um DAO stateless usando JPA que usa o connection pool do Hibernate para aplicar suas transações com o banco de dados. Sempre que o `entityManager` do Hibernate é iniciado, eu tenho a seguinte linha no console do meu servidor:

```
Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
```

Se eu tiver mais de 20 clientes pedindo por transações ao mesmo tempo, o hibernate lança uma exceção sobre o número limite de conexões. Eu devo lidar com esse problema manualmente ou o hibernate tem alguma funcionalidade que permite empilhar os pedidos e ir distribuindo as conexões livres para os clientes em espera?